# Class constructor: Incomplete type is not allowed (in member list) - VS C++ w/ QT

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, constructor, member

I'm having an issue adding this new class/header to this pre-existing project. The project is in VS, written in C++, and integrated with QT. I keep on getting the error that there is "no appropriate default constructor available," and intellisense is highlighting *m_Test(new Proj::Foo)* in the member list for the constructor and saying that "incomplete type is not allowed."

Let's say the project name is Proj, and the class name is Foo.

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "custompanel.h"

class ParameterInterface;
class IsdbServiceInterface;

namespace Proj
{
    class Foo;
}

class Foo : public CustomPanel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Foo(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Foo();

private:
    Proj::Foo* m_Test;
};
#endif
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo(QWidget *parent) : CustomPanel(parent), m_Test(new Proj::Foo)
{
    m_Test->setupUi(this);
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    delete m_Test;
}
```

I've modeled this after other working examples in the project, nothing jumps out to me as to why mine would be any different. Any ideas? I wonder if I'm missing something basic here. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for never completing this question. The answer ended up being more involved with QT...

Basically, I found that they had a THIRD file -> ui_foo.h, generated by qmake.

**ui_foo.h**

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_Foo
{
public:
    void setupUi(QWidget *Foo)
    {
        // Setup stuff here
    }
};

namespace Proj {
    class Foo: public Ui_Foo {};
}

QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

This makes it so that Proj::Foo inherits from Ui_Foo. I'm not sure that this fixes the issue others have brought up how in foo.h there are Proj::Foo and Foo as separate classes, but it works perfectly without altering the code that I originally posted (the brackets DO NOT need to be moved).

It almost appears as though Proj::Foo and Foo are purposefully separate classes. This circumvents the issue Ediac brought up because in Foo's constructor it is calling a constructor for Proj::Foo, thereby avoiding any recursive call. This code is emulated several times by several different people all over the project. No matter how I look at this it still feels wonky...

Answer (score 1):

Your `Foo` class definition is not in the `Proj` namespace, but your `m_test` variable is using the `Proj::Foo` class.

In effect you have two classes: `Foo` and `Proj::Foo`, with `Proj::Foo` having no definition, just a forward declaration.

To fix, either remove the namespace, or expand the namespace braces to include the `Foo` definition.

Comment: .. or simply define the class outside of `Proj` but as `class Proj::Foo : public CustomPanel...`. Once it is declared, you can use qualified name to define it. I.e. you can simply add `Proj::` to the class definition in the current variant.

Answer (score 0):

Like the first person said, you can fix the incomplete type problem by removing the `namespace` or expanding it like `class Proj::Foo : public CustomPanel` and `Foo::Foo(QWidget *parent) : CustomPanel(parent), m_Test(new Proj::Foo)` and `Proj::Foo::~Foo()`.

However, what I want to highlight is this `m_Test(new Proj::Foo)`.

`new` is calling the default constructor of `Proj::Foo`, INSIDE the definition of your default constructor `Foo(QWidget *parent = 0);`, this will result in recursively calling of the constructor and assigning new again, which will cause problems.

One quick workaround is to seperate your existing constructor into two seperate constructors, one that takes an argument `QWidget *parent` and one default constructor that takes no arguments.

```
public:
    explicit Foo(QWidget *parent);
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
```